# insert file data in a SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, file

How can I insert data in a file full of data all together in a table using SQL command?

I am already doing it using `foreach` but what if I do not want to insert row by row but all together?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server, then your best bet there would be `SqlBulkCopy` (with or without a transaction, as you require); for the source you can *either* load all the data from the file into a `DataTable`, *or* in some cases you can create an unbuffered `IDataReader` that streams the data through the file as needed. The `IDataReader` approach is more efficient and faster, but more complex unless a convenient `IDataReader` implementation already exists for your input data (for example, [`CsvReader`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) for delimited data). The `DataTable` approach requires all the data to be buffered in-memory first and is slower, but often more convenient.

Comment: As a note: One thing to keep in mind with bulk copy is: If one of the rows fail to be inserted like for example because of a duplicate key problem the whole insert is cancelled.

Comment: I ma doing this using
public MYTYPE[] res { get; set; }
 FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(MYTYPE)); and then res = engine.ReadFile(FileName) as MYTYPE[];
and then using 'res' I will read line by line and insert. can you help me writing it?